# migration error switching to postgresql in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to switch my RoR app from sqlite3 to postgresql, and deploy it on heroku (it seems that heroku doesn't works good with sqlite)

this is my database.yml

```
default: &default
adapter: sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
 <<: *default
database: db/development.sqlite3


test: &test
 <<: *default
database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
 <<: *default
database: db/production.sqlite3

cucumber:
<<: *test
```

now, switching to postgresql is

```
default: &default
adapter:  postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
 <<: *default
database: development


test: &test
 <<: *default
database: test

production:
 <<: *default
database: production

cucumber:
 <<: *test
```

in gemfile I have replace gem 'sqlite3' with gem 'pg'

typing rails db:migrate the error is

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "development" does not exist
```

Comment: Are you receiving this error in local or in Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems database called `development` is not created in your local system.

You need to create the database before running migration with `rake db:create` command.

Then, you can run the migration with `rake db:migrate`

As @Micael Nussbaumer said, it is better to name your database with your app name as prefix to the environment
**Example: testapp_development**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the names are the environment name prepended by the application name (standard in RoR PG).
So instead of `development`, `yourappname_development`, `production`, `yourappname_production` etc.
Locally should be the same as long as your PG application is well set.

***EDIT:***
I thought the error was on heroku alone, but if it's locally then you'll need to install PG on your local machine, create a database user (this is a one time setup) and then create the database in your rails application (to be done on each application that runs PG), by running: 
`rake db:create`
followed by the migrations. Or `rake db:setup`

On Heroku you don't need to create the Database, but you'll need to run the migrations (every time you need to migrate) unless you specify in the "after-deploy" hook of your `app.json` manifest to run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake db:create` followed by `rake db:migrate` if you are trying on local.

I suggest you to change the name of your database according to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes heroku not work with sqlite.

> Only `pg` database is used on heroku.

So modify your Gemfile with code:

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
```

Using above code, you can work with `sqlite` db on locally and `pg` db is used on `heroku/`